# Set onchange event handler on div to run a function that changes a yet non-existing table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling, datatables

I have a webpage generated by a third-party software. I have little control over generated content, but I can insert some javascript into this webpage. On this webpage there is a button, after it's clicked some time passes (data is dynamically requested from this third-party software and this time varies a lot depending on a request) and a table is generated. This table is generated in a DIV, which ID I know and which was empty before. This table can be manipulated then with other controls (sorted, filtered, amount of elements shown per page changed etc.). It's a DataTables (datatables.net) object. I wrote a function that finds this dynamically created table by ID and changes some formatting of it's contents.

Now the problem is how to set an event handler in a way that when this table is generated or it's contents is changed this function is run. When the page loads for the first time the DIV is empty and there is no table with such ID in DOM. The other problem is that I don't know how all this filtering etc. works. So every time something is changed in a table I need to run my function after all the changes were done (all the other functions finished working).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ***could*** use the [`DOMSubtreeModified`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Mutation_events?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Mutation_events) event

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
        if ($("#dynamicallyCreatedTableID").length>0) {
            //add your event handlers for #dynamicallyCreatedTableID here
        }
    });
});
```

Notice the encapsulation in a `$(document).ready()`-event, This ensures that the event only fires when the button is clicked and the DOM is updated, not when the DOM itself initially is built.

**And YES - I know** `DOMSubtreeModified` **is deprecated, even though it still works in the browsers I tested with**.

Instead, you can achieve the same by using [`DOM MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Here is a modified example from this [blog](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/) :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;
    var body = document.querySelector('body');
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {  
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            if ($("#dynamicallyCreatedTableID").length>0) {
                //add your event handlers for #dynamicallyCreatedTableID here
            }
        });
    });
    observer.observe(body, {
        attributes: false, 
        childList: true, 
        characterData: false 
    });
});
```

The above does exactly the same as the first `DOMSubtreeModified` example